# NSAttributedString - enumerateAttributesInRange causes crash?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsattributedstring

the method `enumerateAttributesInRange` gets a block of code and executes it for every attribute in `NSAttributedString`

- Does it call the bock asynchronously?

When The following method gets called twice in a row really quick 1 after the othr my app gets frozen, I am wondering of it's because enumerateAttributesInRange runs the block of code asynchronously, so 2 threads are trying to modify my AttributedString at the same time.

```
- (void) doSomething
{
   //following line works fine
   [self doSomethingwithAttributedString];

   //following line works fine
   [self doSomethingwithAttributedString];
   [self performSelector:@selector(doSomethingwithAttributedString) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

   //following crashes
    [self doSomethingwithAttributedString];
    [self doSomethingwithAttributedString];
}

- (void)doSomethingwithAttributedString
{
   [self.attributedString enumerateAttributesInRange:_selectedRange options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired usingBlock:
 ^(NSDictionary *attributes, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

          // Here I modify the dictionary and add it back to my attributedString
 }];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are modifying the attributed string while it is being enumerated. I bet this thoroughly confuses the enumerator, since the attributed string it is working on is not in the state it was in when it started enumerating. In the block, only *collect* the attributes, e.g. in a dictionary or array, but modify them and apply them to the string *afterward*, i.e. after the enumeration is finished.

In other words: don't put code that modifies the attributed string inside the block that is called during enumeration. The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say you can modify the attributed string inside the range on which the block applies, but ISTM you must take enormous care not to go outside. I wouldn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but adding `[self.attributedString beginEditing];` before and `[self.attributedString endEditing];` after seem to solve the crash.

Comment: Also, don't forget to test the dictionary key for a nil object.